# LaserScan Message vs MultiEchoLaserScan Message

Tags: ros, navigation, cartographer, ros-kinetic, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I want to compare cartographer and gmapping.
Gmapping uses LaserScan Message and cartographer uses MultiEchoLaserScan Message for Lidar data.
What is difference between them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298720/laserscan-message-vs-multiecholaserscan-message/) by [js.kim.aspl@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/36642/js.kim.aspl@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The standard [Laser scan message](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html) describes only a single returned depth and intensity value for each laser pulse, this is usually the most intense if there are several but this depends on your sensor hardware.

Multi-echo sensors are able to return several echos for each pulse emitted by the laser. For example if you scan through a window you will often pickup an echo from the glass as well as the wall behind it, or at the boundary of two objects at different depths you can receive two echo's for the depth of each object. This additional information gives you more points which can be used to create your map and localise the robot. So a node that receives [multi echo laser scan messages](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/MultiEchoLaserScan.html) can use this type of sensors to their full potential.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2018-11-22**:
Hi Pete, may I know which sensor will give me the MultiEchoLaserScan sensor msgs? like which brand and which type, many thanks.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-11-23**:
Can you ask this as a new question. An old closed question is not a good place for this.

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2018-12-17**:
Hi Pete, as you suggested, post a new question here
https://answers.ros.org/question/310825/which-sensor-will-give-out-the-multiecholaserscan-sensor-msgs-which-brand-and-which-type/